# Egypt Comic Strip - Like 'Wizard of Id' or 'BC'

Tags: story-identification, comics

There was a comic strip I read around the 90s set in Ancient Egypt. It had pyramids and featured walking, talking mummies cracking jokes, etc.

It was a bit like *The Wizard of Id* and *BC* in style, but I do not think it was by either of those creators.

Comment: Are there any fantasy or sci-fi aspects to it?

Comment: The mummies were talking and cracking jokes, so probably fantasy. I cannot guarentee it is not completely factual as I have not stayed in museums or pyramids to hear the potential banter of mummies. :)

Comment: FWIW the *Wizard of Id* and *BC* were created by the *same* cartoonist, [Johnny Hart](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Johnny_Hart) (no evidence that he ever did anything Egypt-related)

Comment: You are right. I even looked up Brant Parker (the other artist for the Wizard of Id) and could not see this Egyptian comic strip to his credits. I can remember seeing another one of his books in the same book store when I bought the Egyptian ones; namely Crock the Foreign Legion cartoon. They all had a similar style.

Comment: It makes me think of [Nilus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nilus_(comics)), but I don't know if it was ever published outside of Italy.

Comment: Was this in a UK newspaper? I'm sure I saw a comic strip like this in a newspaper, and since I don't buy newspapers it would have to have been in my mum's Daily Mail.

Comment: Where did you live when you read this?

Comment: Do you remember if it was in colour or black and  white please?

Comment: @McTrooper Nilus is very possibly it. The style is exactly the same. However, the strips I was reading appeared to have more about the mummies. Maybe it was a phase the artist was in at the point I read it. I have looked at the other characters in [link](http://origone.net/ita/nilus.html), but I cannot remember them. However, this does say it was translated into other languages which is a positive.

Comment: @John, ArlettaS Judith It was not in a newspaper. I used to go to a bookshop in Bath UK in the 90s and late 80s and buy little books of comic strips. The front cover was colour, but the pages inside were B&W.  Maybe A5 size, possibly smaller. Peanuts, The Wizard of Id, BC, this Egyptian one. There might have been others, but these were my favourites.

Comment: Sluggy Freelance had a [story arc](https://archives.sluggy.com/book.php?chapter=9#1998-12-06) in 1998 in which some characters were trapped in pyramid for a period of time. I don't think the story had talking mummies, but each strip normally contains jokes. Sluggy strips are eventually reprinted as books.

Comment: @Kenster: I do remember some talking mummies (although part of the joke was that the mummy moved and talked so slowly that they couldn't understand it), but *Sluggy* also had a very distinctive art style that I don't think could be mistaken for Hart's.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Possibly *King Tutt* by Geoff Watson.

(I have vague memories of an ancient Egyptian comedy strip like you describe, and the name King Tutt came to mind - Unfortunately I can find very little information about it online - search provided the name Geoff Watson, and what little information there is seems to match my memories).

[This site](http://www.tonystrading.co.uk/galleries/comicstrips/kingtutt.htm) lists some of the published books and has a few strip excerpts.

[image: Image from King Tutt]

Comment: [There'S a collection of the Kung Tutt books here.](http://www.tonystrading.co.uk/galleries/comicstrips/kingtutt.htm)  There's a couple of (fragments) from the comics as well.

Comment: Added link from JRE and an image

Comment: This one is the one I was trying to find. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

Slightly expanding from my comment, it could be [*Nilus*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nilus_(comics)), an Italian comic strip set in the ancient Egypt.

It follows the adventures of a group of characters in the ancient Egypt (the eponymous Nilus who is the BF of the pharaoh's daughter, the pharaoh himself, the high priest, and so on) and has the format of a 3 panel strip.

You can find some more information in the [Italian Wikipedia entry](https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nilus)

I don't remember talking mummies in the comics of Nilus I read, but the same authors also created another comic strip, [*Mommy*](http://www.quipos.net/it/personaggi-famosi/mommy/), which was about a mummy that awakened in our time. Often, its adventures were in the same publications of *Nilus*, so that could be what the OP remembers.

Comment: This was not the one I was after, but this does look really good. I am going to look some more into this. Hopefully I can find an English version.